# Unable to enter data into mysql

Tags: php, mysql

A php script which is intended to enter data into the database is working selectively. Data for 5th and 10th grade gets in but data for all other grades wont show up. I have checked the if else blocks and the logic is working just fine its executing the inner blocks as it is supposed to just wont enter any data into the database. For grades other than 5th or 10th the 2nd block gets executed and i have already checked that it echos the correct value of stuff it is supposed to enter the database. and using a echo after the sql() query i also found out that its working too, so kind of stuck no idea whats wrong please help.

here is the code, let me know if you guys need the html too

```
<?php
$roll=$_POST['roll'];
$marks=$_POST['marks'];
$dbase=$_POST['std'];
$sec=$_POST['sec'];
$sec1=$_POST['sec1'];
$expire= time()+60;
if (empty($roll) || empty($marks) || ($dbase==0))
{

echo '<p align="center">You did not enter all data. Please go back and enter them.</p>';
echo '<FORM><p align="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></p></FORM>';
die();
}
else
{
    if($dbase==5)
    {
        $temp="five";
    }
    if($dbase==6)
    {
        $temp="six";
    }
    if($dbase==7)
    {
        $temp="seven";
    }
    if($dbase==8)
    {
        $temp="eight";
    }
    if($dbase==9)
    {
        $temp="nine";
    }
    if($dbase==10)
    {
        $temp="ten";
    }
    if($dbase==11)
    {
        $temp="eleven";
    }
    if($dbase==12)
    {
        $temp="twelve";
    }
if(($dbase==5)&&($sec=="0"))
{
    echo '<p align="center">You did not enter all data. Please go back and enter them. 2</p>';
    echo '<FORM><p align="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></p></FORM>';
    die();
}
else
{
    if($dbase<6)
    {
    $sect=$sec;
    setcookie("tab", $temp, $expire, "/","skc-hs.com");
    $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="data"; // Database name
    $tbl_name=$temp; // Table name
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $roll = stripslashes($roll);
    $marks = stripslashes($marks);
    $roll = mysql_real_escape_string($roll);
    $marks = mysql_real_escape_string($marks);
    $sql="insert into $tbl_name (roll , marks, std, sec) values ('$roll' , '$marks' , '$dbase' , '$sect')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    header( 'Location: dcreate.html');
    die();
    }
}
if(($dbase!=10)&&($dbase!=5)&&($sec1=="0"))
{
    echo '<p align="center">You did not enter all data. Please go back and enter them. 3</p>';
    echo '<FORM><p align="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></p></FORM>';
    die();
}
else
{
    if(($dbase!=5)&&($dbase!=10))
    {
    $sect=$sec1;
    setcookie("tab", $temp, $expire, "/","skc-hs.com");
    $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="data"; // Database name
    $tbl_name=$temp; // Table name
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $roll = stripslashes($roll);
    $marks = stripslashes($marks);
    $roll = mysql_real_escape_string($roll);
    $marks = mysql_real_escape_string($marks);
    $sql="insert into $tbl_name (roll , marks, std, sec) values ('$roll' , '$marks' , '$dbase' '$sect')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    header( 'Location: dcreate.html');
    die();
    }
}

if($dbase==10)
{
    setcookie("tab", $temp, $expire, "/","skc-hs.com");
    $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="data"; // Database name
    $tbl_name=$temp; // Table name
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $roll = stripslashes($roll);
    $marks = stripslashes($marks);
    $roll = mysql_real_escape_string($roll);
    $marks = mysql_real_escape_string($marks);
    $sql="insert into $tbl_name (roll , marks, std) values ('$roll' , '$marks' , '$dbase')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    header( 'Location: dcreate.html');
    die();
}


}
?>
```

Structure of table(expect for the table "ten")

Column  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default ExtraAction
id  int(11)                 No      None    AUTO_INCREMENT
roll    varchar(3)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None
marks   smallint(6)                 No  None                    std     varchar(2)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None
sec     varchar(1)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None

Structure of table ten

Column  Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default ExtraAction
id  int(11)                 No      None    AUTO_INCREMENT
roll    varchar(3)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None
marks   smallint(6)                 No  None                    std     varchar(2)  latin1_swedish_ci   No  None

when i modify the 2nd if block like this

```
if(($dbase!=5)&&($dbase!=10))
    {
    $sect=$sec1;
            echo "roll- ";
            echo $roll;
            echo "  marks- ";
            echo $marks;
            echo " std- ";
            echo $dbase;
            echo " section- ";
            echo $sect;
            setcookie("tab", $temp, $expire, "/","skc-hs.com");
    $host="127.0.0.1"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="data"; // Database name
    $tbl_name=$temp; // Table name
    // Connect to server and select databse.
    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $roll = stripslashes($roll);
    $marks = stripslashes($marks);
    $roll = mysql_real_escape_string($roll);
    $marks = mysql_real_escape_string($marks);
    $sql="insert into $tbl_name (roll , marks, std, sec) values ('$roll' , '$marks' , '$dbase' '$sect')";
    mysql_query($sql);
    echo " done";
    die();
    }
```

it echos "roll- 12 marks- 454 std- 7 section- B done" when i enter those values in the html form. I dont get it why it won't just enter those values in the database

Comment: var_dump($dbase) before you run into the first if() comparison, I don't think ==0 is a strong (accurate) enough comparison ...

Comment: Would be interesting to see the table's structure, because it seems you insert into sometimes 4, sometimes 3 columns.

Comment: oh dear you need some DRY lessons

Comment: not helpful @HappyApe please be more specific

Comment: The if statements are working checked them using echo. @Cups

Comment: Can you add a call to [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) after your calls to `mysql_query`. There's a pretty good chance that the server is telling you about some problem its having

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forget to place a comma betwwen `$dbase` and  `$sect` in query.

Change the query  from

```
   $sql="insert into $tbl_name (roll , marks, std, sec) 
          values ('$roll' , '$marks' , '$dbase' '$sect')";
```

to

```
   $sql="insert into $tbl_name (roll , marks, std, sec)
          values ('$roll' , '$marks' , '$dbase' , '$sect')";
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to `exit()` the script if anything isn't a 10 or a 5 with this code:

```
if(($dbase!=10)&&($dbase!=5)&&($sec1=="0"))
{
    echo '<p align="center">You did not enter all data. Please go back and enter them. 3</p>';
    echo '<FORM><p align="center"><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Go Back" onClick="history.go(-1);return true;"></p></FORM>';
    die();
}
```

Comment: if $dbase is say 7 and $sec1 is say "A" then the code wont exit() I have used && not || so i think all the 3 condition should be satisfied for the exit() to happen. And yes i do need the script to exit if $dbase is not a 10 or 5 when $sec1 is 0